# Set icon for drop-down navigation list in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application, I want to display icon in place of the "bookmark" in the action bar. I tried searching a lot of places but no help.[image]

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: do you want to show text and icon, both together?

Comment: I only want to show the icon for the drop down list.

Comment: can you post your menu's xml?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to subclass the SpinnerAdapter and in its getDropDownView method you have to supply a custom layout with an icon and a label.

You can find an example here: http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to show icon as your menu item, you need to include the following attributes:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
android:icon="@drawable/what_ever_your_icon"
```